# Visual Studio 2008 Setup Project does not include VC_redist

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2008, installation, redistributable

I know this must have been answered before, but I cannot find a reference...

Problem:  How do I configure a Visual Studio setup project to include and install the VC redist package?

Info:
I am creating a Visual Studio 2008 C# Win Forms project that uses native code through a managed C++ dll.  In order to install this program on users computers, I made a Visual Studio Setup project.  The only problem is, I cannot seem to get the x86_redist package to be included in the install, thus, the program fails to launch on users computers who do not have VS.  (Yes, this is a Release build.)  I have attempted adding a PreRequisite in the C# program, and I have attempted adding a Merge Module in the setup program.

Thanks for the help!

---

More detail:

The exact error message is this:  Exception caught!  System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly "MyInterface, Version=1.0.5354.28734, ..." or one of its dependencies.  The application has failed to start because the application configuration is incorrect.  Reinstalling the application may fix the problem.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)

That HRESULT is a COM Exception, and essentially seems to wave its hands and say "Something bad happened".  Any hints?

Comment: Look in the Windows application event log.  You'll get detailed info about what is wrong with the manifest.  No point guessing at it until you post what you see there.

Comment: Not very helpful (to me):  .NET Runtime 2.0 Error  Description:  EventType clr20r3, P1 mycompany.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 537d2160, p4 mycompany, P5 1.0.0.0, P6 537d2160, P7 2e, P8 35, P9 system.io.fileloadexception, P10 NIL.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong event.